# Calculate total prices of catalog?

Tags: price, catalog, products

This may be an unusual request, but it is possible to generate the sum of prices in the catalog?

In other words, get the sum dollar amount for a range of products or all products in the catalog?

Thanks in advance for any assistance or insight provided. Trying to help a difficult client!

Comment: Thanks for the code, David. Can anyone tell me the best place to place it?

Answer (score 0):

do you just want to sum up the prices of all products in the shop? This should be something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class GetTotalSumOfAllProductPrices
{
    /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
    private $productRepository;

    /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function getSum()
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        return array_reduce($this->productRepository->getList(searchCriteria)->getItems(), function (float $sum, ProductInterface $product) {
            return $sum += $product->getFinalPrice();
        }, 0.0);
    }
}
```

If you want for example only visible products or any other constraint, you can use the searchCriteriaBuilder to limit the search to specific products

Comment: Thanks David. I appreciate the help. Total newb follow up, but where would you implement this code? Just curious what is best practice. Thanks.

Comment: David. I've added the code to a .phtml file and called it via a block. Do I need to add an echo to your code to display the total?